# Updating the SubscriberKey on the All Subscriber table through the API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, ampscript

I'm trying to update an existing Subscriber in the All Subscriber Table through the API; i've set up the AppId in the App Center and have connected and created Subscribers, but i'm still having issues updating.

What call do I need to be making to do this? These are the ones i've been trying.

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/putDataExtensionRowByKey.html
https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/createContacts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't change the SubscriberKey without an SFMC Services engagement.